# Ember yield multiple actions into component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a `checkout-form` component which has some actions like `next`, `previous`, `submitForm` and `selectDate`. Currently I’m only able to `yield` the `selectDate` action like this:

```
{{!-- checkout-form.js --}}
<div class='checkout-form'>
  {{yield (action 'selectDate')}}
</div>
```

I’d like to be able to use my `checkout-form` component like this:

```
{{!-- order.hbs --}}
{{#checkout-form as |submitForm, selectDate|}} 
  {{checkout-field placeholder="Full Name" value=model.order.name}}
  {{!-- another field component that uses selectDate --}}
  {{checkout-form-actions action=submitForm}}
{{/checkout-form}}
```

How would I go about yielding multiple actions to be used inside of my `checkout-form.hbs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**option 1.** You can pass many arguments like below

```
{{yield (action 'selectDate') (action 'submitForm')}}
```

Read - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/block-params/

and

```
{{!-- order.hbs --}}
{{#checkout-form as |selectDate, submitForm|}} 
  {{checkout-form-actions action=selectDate}}
  {{checkout-form-actions action=submitForm}}
{{/checkout-form}}
```

**option 2.** You can also use [hash helper](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14.1/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/hash?anchor=hash&show=inherited,protected,private,deprecated),

```
{{yield (hash 
        selectDate=(action 'selectDate')
        submitForm=(action 'submitForm')) }}
```

and

```
{{#checkout-form as |options|}}   
  {{checkout-form-actions action=options.submitForm}}
{{/checkout-form}}
```